# From java -jar myApp.jar -options to myApp -options

Tags: java, command-line, jar, executable

I've created a **JAVA COMMAND LINE** application that runs like this :

`java -jar myApp.jar -param1 opt1 -param2 opt2 -param3 opt3`

No I'm trying to create an executable of myApp so I could run it like this :

`myApp -param1 opt1 -param2 opt2 -param3 opt3`

I've used `Launch4j` but it didn't work.

How can I create the executable of myApp so I could run it as I want in both **Win** and **Linux**  ?

Comment: you could have done a script if it only was "win" or "linux". however y don't you write a wrapper and run "myApp.jar" as a subprocess given the appropriate param

Comment: @nafas Could you please give me more details concerning writing a wrapper ?

Comment: wrapper is basically a class with main method that calls other processes(in your case myApp.jar). basically you can add parameters to your processes using ProcessBuilder class. of course it would make sense if those parameters don't change(or you can acquire them automatically from a source).

Comment: @nafas Actually I solved this issue. Using `Launch4j`, I had to choose `Header type : console`. That's it. It works as I want now.